# How to create a vector by combining rows of a data frame in R?

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

I have a data frame say 'a'

```
qq  ee  rr  tt
1    2   3   4
2    44  66  77
9    0   0   4
```

I want a create a vector like:

```
vec <- c(1,2,3,4,2,44,66,77,9,0,0,4)
```

how do I do this?

Comment: Did you do any googling/searching SO on your own behalf?

Comment: Even the worst R programmer should know this can be done by a double-loop over i=cols and j=rows. It might not be the best way, but it would at least show us you had some competency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take the `t`ranspose which also converts it to a `matrix`, and then convert to `vector`:

```
as.vector(t(a))
 [1]  1  2  3  4  2 44 66 77  9  0  0  4
```

Comment: @jmsigner, that's using `c` for its side effect, as opposed to `as.vector`, which I find more transparent.

Comment: There is a quote from Prof. Ripley somewhere, that you shouldn't use `c` for it's side effect. Wasn't it even a `fortune`?

Comment: @Roland, `fortune(185)`.

Answer (score 2):

Use James' answer.

Here is another alternative: `unlist` and sort.

```
unlist(a)[order(rep(seq_len(nrow(a)),ncol(a)))]
#qq1 ee1 rr1 tt1 qq2 ee2 rr2 tt2 qq3 ee3 rr3 tt3 
#  1   2   3   4   2  44  66  77   9   0   0   4
```

That way you retain information in names, which could be useful. If you don't want the names, use `unlist` with `use.names=FALSE`.

Comment: +1 Ah, that answers my question

Comment: you beat me to it by just 35 minutes!

Answer (score 0):

For fun, here's another alternative:

```
> scan(textConnection(do.call(paste, a)))
Read 12 items
 [1]  1  2  3  4  2 44 66 77  9  0  0  4
```

Where "a" is:

```
a <- read.table(textConnection("qq  ee  rr  tt
 1    2   3   4
 2    44  66  77
 9    0   0   4"), header=T)
```